# Free park and ride between Siegburg and airport DUS?

Tags: germany, budget, automobiles, dusseldorf, dus

I consider how close I can find a free park and ride to Dusseldorf airport as coming from Siegburg (Germany) ?

Answer (score 2):

On [www.gratisparken.de](http://www.gratisparken.de/Nordrhein-Westfalen/Duesseldorf/) you can find a lot of free parking places in and around Düsseldorf. The closest to the airport are on these streets:

- Im Grund
- Lohauser Dorfstr.
- Brandenburgerstr.

And on [www.duesseldorf.de](https://www.duesseldorf.de/fileadmin/Amt66/verkehrsmanagement/grafik/mit_dem_Auto/parkride.jpg) there is also a map with all official P&R in Düsseldorf.

Comment: thanks - best option is actually *Brandenburgerstr.* because from there you can get to the airport with the bus 760 under 20 minutes, others make no sense.

Comment: @J.Doe be aware that these aren't "Park + Ride" locations, but just areas where it should be possible for you to find a parking spot (including just some space on the side of the road, in the case of at least two - and I think all three - mentioned in the answer). I don't know anything about Düsseldorf so can't comment on how good the advice is, but I took a look at the locations that site suggests in Hamburg - some strike me "optimistic", to put it rather mildly.